# Android не могу получить id новой заметки

Tags: java, android-studio

пытаюсь учиться программированию, нигде не могу найти ответа на вопрос.
Пишу приложение заметки. Базу данных использую Room. Когда создаю новую заметку и нажимаю сохранить, она сохраняется, но присвоенный ей id недоступен. Если выйти из заметки и открыть ее из списка сохраненных, то все в порядке. Возможно ли как-то получить id последней созданной заметки, не выходя из нее? Ну или на программном уровне выполнить выход и открытие созданной заметки?

Возможно необходимо прикрепить какой-то код? Весь код думаю загадит вопрос.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Метод, помеченный как @Insert в DAO, может возвращать id вставленной записи - добавьте long как возвращаемый тип. Или массив/коллекцию long, если вставляется сразу несколько записей.

https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/accessing-data#convenience-insert

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, попробую покопать в этом направлении, я вместо long использовал int.

Comment: Огромное спасибо разобрался! Неделю голову ломал :)